# Detect long-press using Keybow

Tags: python

I'm trying to use this python library https://github.com/pimoroni/keybow-python to control a raspberry pi (initiate events, e.g. launch a script or shutdown the pi).

This works will so far. I'm struggling to detect a long press. The API linked above allows 'catching' the event of pressing the button or releasing it. Not sure how I go about measuring the time between one and the other... I tried this:

`

```
def time_string_to_decimals(time_string):
    fields = time_string.split(":")
    hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
    minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
    seconds = fields[2] if len(fields) > 2 else 0.0
    return float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0) + (float(seconds) / pow(60.0, 2))

while True:
  t = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
  now = time_string_to_decimals(t)

  @keybow.on()
  def handle_key(index, state):
    key0Up = 0
    key0Down = 0

    if index == 0 and state:
      key0Down = now
      print ("down: " + str(now))
    if index == 0 and not state:
      key0Up = now
      downtime = key0Up - key0Down
      print ("down: " + str(now))
      print ("up: " + str(now))
      print ("downtime: " + str(downtime))
      if downtime >= 0.001:
        print ("shutdown!")
    if index == 3 and not state:
      print ("Hello!")
    if index == 6 and not state:
      print ("World!")
```

`

... the print commands are just to follow what's going on. The problem is that the key0Down also get's set to the current time when the button is released. I'm stumped. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Best regards,
Andrew

See above... I keep getting the same 'timestamp' for the key Down und key Up event...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your issue is that when the `@keybow.on` decorator attaches the callback it has a static value for `now` that doesn't get updated by the while loop which will be in a different scope. Repeatedly declaring the callback during the while loop looks wrong also.

I don't have this hardware so it is not possible for me to test this. However, looking through the repository you linked to I would be tempted to do the following...

As you need to share the key events timings between functions I would put them into a class and have class variables for the key0up and key0down values.

I have also gone for different event handlers for the different keys to simplify the complex chain of `if` statements.

I was not sure if the keybow `on` decorator would do the right thing if used inside a class, so I have attached callbacks to keys without using a decorator.

```py
import keybow
import time


class MyKeys:
    key0Up = 0
    key0Down = 0

    def handle_key0(self, index, state):
        if state:
            self.key0Down = time.time()
            print("down: ", self.key0Down)
        elif not state:
            self.key0Up = time.time()
            downtime = self.key0Up - self.key0Down
            print("down: ", self.key0Down)
            print("up: ", self.key0Up)
            print("downtime: ", downtime)
            if downtime >= 1:  # Greater than 1 second
                print("shutdown!")

    def handle_key3(self, index, state):
        if not state:
            print("Hello!")

    def handle_key6(self, index, state):
        if not state:
            print("World!")


def main():
    my_keys = MyKeys()
    keybow.on(0, my_keys.handle_key0)
    keybow.on(3, my_keys.handle_key3)
    keybow.on(6, my_keys.handle_key6)
    while True:
        keybow.show()
        time.sleep(1.0 / 60.0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: THANKS! That works exactly as I wanted it to... So grateful! Thanks again.